# Dropdown Multiselect Check Mark Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Based from this code http://jsfiddle.net/bs5rc6k3/3/ I created a dropdown list where when you select an option it will add an check mark beside the option. but this is only for single select. How can I change it to a toggle function where I can add check mark to each of the option I selected instead, in other word multiple select check mark?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="button-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Column Filter</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
           <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#" class="toggle-vis" data-column="0"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="toggle-vis" data-column="1"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="toggle-vis" data-column="2"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> C</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="toggle-vis" data-column="3"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> D</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $('#myDropdown > li > a').click(function(e){
        $('#myDropdown > li > a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
#myDropdown > li > a > .fa{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#myDropdown > li > a.selected > .fa{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: you can use selectpicker for this, it provide everything which you need. https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i tried it before it didn't work, probably because theres a conflict with my datatable function. but answer by Alex below has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method instead of `addClass()` and do not remove this from others. Add `dropdown('toggle')` to prevent the menu collapsing after click on an item.

```
$('#myDropdown > li > a').click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
});
```